# I am getting a web page not found error after deploying web app on server

Tags: java, web-applications, wildfly-12

[image]So when I deployed my web app on the server there were no errors but the browser won't load the web page. here is the log:

```
 20:23:58,125 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "ProjectFE.war" (runtime-name: "ProjectFE.war")
20:24:01,700 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
20:24:01,705 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
20:24:01,705 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
20:24:01,716 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
20:24:01,721 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
20:24:01,738 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
20:24:01,741 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0013: Deployment ProjectFE.war contains CDI annotations but no bean archive was found (no beans.xml or class with bean defining annotations was present).
20:24:01,768 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = ProjectFE.war_org.h2.Driver_1_4
20:24:01,866 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 244) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
20:24:01,866 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 244) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
20:24:01,866 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 244) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
20:24:03,468 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 244) Root WebApplicationContext initialized in 1602 ms
20:24:03,479 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 244) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP5  for context '/ProjectFE'
20:24:06,018 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 244) Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'appServlet'
20:24:06,018 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 244) Initializing Servlet 'appServlet'
20:24:06,466 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 244) Completed initialization in 448 ms
20:24:06,466 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 244) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/ProjectFE' for server 'default-server'
20:24:06,531 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "ProjectFE.war" (runtime-name : "ProjectFE.war")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your web.xml's welcome page properly set?

Please also add your war sources (link to GIT or whatsoever)...

Comment: yes, i've properly setup my web.xml, still it won't work

Comment: Do you have your project somewhere at github to see the sources?

Comment: Well I haven't created a repository, but I think I'll create one and then post the link. Thanks for your patience buddy.

Comment: I have created a seperate question, because I think I've asked it incorectly, also i've posted my code there, here's the link to question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53885379/getting-an-error-org-springframework-web-servlet-pagenotfound-default-task-1